# How can I add a label widget after the main window has been initialized?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm tying to add a label Widget after the `MainWindow` has been initialized. It work fine if I call the function in `MainWindow` but not from another function, the function is executed , however does not add the new label to the window.

```
QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
    self.shadow.setBlurRadius(50)
    self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
    self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
    self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
    self.setWindowTitle(" NetView ")
    # QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip)
    self.ui.minimizeBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
    self.ui.resmaxBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.restore_or_maximize_window())
    self.ui.closeBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
    self.ui.lockBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.netLock())
    self.ui.unlockBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.unLock())

    ## works fine
    self.createNewWidget(0,0,"test")

def createNewWidget(self, rowNumber, columNumber, client_name):
    new_label_name = 'label_'+client_name
    #print(new_label_name)
    self.label_new = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.label_new.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))
    self.label_new.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))
    #self.label_new.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,85,255);")
    self.label_new.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.label_new.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.label_new.setObjectName(new_label_name)

def createdisplay(self)
    ##does not work
    self.createNewWidget(0,1,"test1")
```

Comment: Adding `self.label_new.show()` would theoretically solve the problem, but the real issue is that you should actually use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work, added it to at the end of createNewWidget and ceatedisplay function.

Comment: As already said, you should use layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an extremeally simple GUI i created recently, should give you an answer:

Qlabel is what you should pay most attention to :)

```
class Window(QMainWindow): 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Server Checker")
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.textOutput = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textOutput.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textOutput.resize(280, 300)
        self.textOutput.move(10, 5)

        self.serversCheckedtoScreen = QLabel("Servers Checked: ", self)
        self.serversCheckedtoScreen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.serversFailed = QLabel("Total Servers Offline: 0", self)
        self.serversFailed.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self, objectName="progressBar")  
        self.pbar.setGeometry(200, 80, 280, 20)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Check Servers", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textOutput)
        layout.addWidget(self.serversCheckedtoScreen)
        layout.addWidget(self.serversFailed)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)

        self.pbar.setStyleSheet("""
        QWidget {
            text-align: center;
            }
        """)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
```

It creates an instance of a small window, with an output area, two labels and a progress bar. It also uses layout manager. There is technically a .show() missing, however I have that bit of code in the main, hence its missing here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I created the window using QT designer, and works fine, all I want to do is to add a label  to the main window by calling a function from another one. It works fine if I have a button to execute the function.

Comment: tried calling this: ```def createdisplay(self)
    ##does not work
    createNewWidget(0,1,"test1")```
with self?
```self.createNewWidget(0,1,"test1")```

Comment: sorry that did not work, the function is executed, however does not add new label to the window.